# How to use the sync.WaitGroup to execute all the goroutine?

Tags: go

Currently I am pushing all the values to the channel and reading from it and doing the square of it.
I want to avoid using `time.Sleep(2000 * time.Millisecond)` since it's blocking the execution for 2 seconds instead I want every goroutine to process and wait for its execution and then exit the program. I just got out of touch with golang so asking this basic question now :(. Can anyone help me with this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func doSquare(num int) int {
    return num * num
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {

    wg.Add(1)
    st := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    quit := make(chan bool)
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := range st {
            ch <- i
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case x := <-ch:
                fmt.Println(doSquare(x))
                // return

            case <-quit:
                wg.Done()
            default:
                // fmt.Println("---")
                // do something
            }
        }
    }()

    quit <- true

    wg.Wait()
    time.Sleep(2000 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move `quit <- true` to the end of the first goroutine

```
func main() {
    wg.Add(1)
    st := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    quit := make(chan bool)
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := range st {
            ch <- i
        }
        quit <- true
    }()

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case x := <-ch:
                fmt.Println(doSquare(x))
                // return

            case <-quit:
                wg.Done()
                return
            default:
                // fmt.Println("---")
                // do something
            }
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

This is another way to signal there is no more data by `close(ch)`

```
func main() {
    st := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    quit := make(chan bool)
    ch := make(chan int) // improve concurrency by `ch := make(chan int, 100)`
    go func() {
        for i := range st {
            ch <- i
        }
        close(ch)
    }()

    go func() {
        for x := range ch {
            fmt.Println(doSquare(x))
        }
        quit <- true
    }()

    <-quit
}
```

Comment: :O it solves the issue. May I ask how putting the quit <- true in go func solve the issue ?
Just curious

Comment: The second goroutine will consume the data, which is produced by the first goroutine. After all the data has been consumed, the second goroutine needs to be informed that there are no more data. `quit <- true` is one of the ways.

Comment: can you explain the last line: `<-quit`?

Comment: It serves the purpose of waiting for the second goroutine to finish. As you can see, the second goroutine will `quit <- true` when finishing its job.